# Select constant value

Tags: oracle, select, constants

I have 2 views:

1. View `VIEW5_SUMA` that contains SUM of prices for all items (cars), it is one row and it's constant I need to "join"
2. View `VIEW4_SUMA_AUTA` that contains SUM of all incomes for specific item (car)

`SQL> SELECT * FROM VIEW5_SUMA ;`

```
CELKOVA_TRZBA
-------------
         5806

SQL> SELECT * FROM VIEW4_SUMA_AUTA ;

TRZBA_AUTA    ID_AUTO
---------- ----------
       360          1
       ...        ...
```

I need to create another view, that will contain percents of income for every item. The problem is, I dont know how to "JOIN" that one row from `VIEW5_SUMA` (constant of total income) to my select so I can calculate with it.

This is what I got so far but it returns error:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW6 AS
SELECT
  t1.typ,
  t1.specifikacia_typu,
  t1.SPZ,
  t2.trzba_auta/(t3.celkova_trzba/100) AS percenta
FROM AUTA t1, VIEW5_SUMA t3
JOIN VIEW4_SUMA_AUTA t2 ON t1.id_auto = t2.id_auto
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you see is due to the fact that the `JOIN` binds tighter than the comma so what you wrote is equivalent to

```
FROM AUTA t1, (VIEW5_SUMA t3 JOIN VIEW4_SUMA_AUTA t2 ON t1.id_auto = t2.id_auto)
```

Seeing how there is no table `t1` inside the parenthesis this won't work.

That means all you have to do is to change the order so that the binding works as you want it:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW6 AS
 SELECT
  t1.typ,
  t1.specifikacia_typu,
  t1.SPZ,
  t2.trzba_auta/(t3.celkova_trzba/100) AS percenta
 FROM AUTA t1 JOIN VIEW4_SUMA_AUTA t2 ON t1.id_auto = t2.id_auto,
 VIEW5_SUMA t3
 ;
```

Alternatively you can use a `CROSS JOIN` which is the same thing as a comma because it results in a cartesian product or changes into an `inner join` if there is a `where` clause.

```
 FROM AUTA t1 CROSS JOIN VIEW5_SUMA t3 JOIN VIEW4_SUMA_AUTA t2 ON (...)

 FROM AUTA t1 JOIN VIEW4_SUMA_AUTA t2 ON (...) CROSS JOIN VIEW5_SUMA t3
```

The `CROSS JOIN` is a `JOIN` so you have the expected parenthesis `((CROSS JOIN) JOIN )`

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found one way just after posting my question. If I dont use `JOIN` at all but rather specify multiple tables in `FROM` and then join tables with `WHERE` it works.

```
SELECT
  t1.typ,
  t1.specifikacia_typu,
  t1.SPZ,
  t2.trzba_auta/(t3.celkova_trzba/100) AS percenta
FROM AUTA t1, VIEW4_SUMA_AUTA t2, VIEW5_SUMA t3
WHERE
  t1.id_auto = t2.id_auto
;
```

But I'm still curious if there's way to do this with `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

'Returns error' is not helpful in diagnosing the problem. I'd guess it says that `t1.id_auto` is an invalid identifier.

Mixing the [old join syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm) (multiple comma-separated tables in the `from` clause and the join condition in the `where` clause) and the ['new' syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2080416) (`join` and `on`) is confusing and doesn't always work; I'd recommend always using the 'new' syntax anyway.

You can do this with `join`, but you have to only use that form. Since there is no join condition between `t1` and `t3`, you need a [`cross join`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#sthref6758). This produces the cartesian product of the two tables, which isn't often what you want, but in this case since one the of the tables has a single row it seems appropriate.

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW6 AS
SELECT
  t1.typ,
  t1.specifikacia_typu,
  t1.SPZ,
  t2.trzba_auta/(t3.celkova_trzba/100) AS percenta
FROM AUTA t1
CROSS JOIN VIEW5_SUMA t3
JOIN VIEW4_SUMA_AUTA t2 ON t1.id_auto = t2.id_auto
```

Building views on top of views isn't always a good idea and can cause performance issues.